# Writing a function which applies another function to a list of numbers in python

Tags: python, list, function

First I had to write a python function such that f(n) equals

5, if n is divisible by 5 but not by 7
7, if n is divisible by 7 but not by 5
35, if n is divisible by 7 and by 5
0 otherwise.

I have done this (as seen below)

```
def f(n):
if n % 5 == 0 and n % 7 != 0:
    return 5
elif n % 7 == 0 and n % 5 != 0:
    return 7
elif n % 7 == 0 and n % 5 == 0:
    return 35
else:
    return 0
```

I need to now create another function `k(a, b)` which returns a list consisting of the numbers f(a), f(a+1), ..., f(b) in that order, where f is the function from above.

For example, k(4, 6) should be the list [f(4), f(5), f(6)] which is [0, 5, 0]

This is what I have done so far. Bear in mind I need to begin this function with `def k(a,b)` such that when I call
`print (k(4, 6))` for instance it will return [0, 5, 0]

```
def k(a, b):
    output = []
    for n in k(a, b):
        output.append(f(n))
        return output
```

But I am not getting the correct result. If anyone could help with this last section would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have the return indented one too many times. It returns after the function has been called once, instead of after the iteration is finished. It should look like this.

```
def k(a, b):
    output = []
    for n in range(a, b):
        output.append(f(n))
    return output
```

To shorten the code, it can look like this:

```
def k(a, b):
    output = [f(n) for n in range(a, b)]
    return output
```

Comment: Thank you very much!